# Oracle SQL for order does not have a item "pencil" and then sql will the order. otherwise it will not return

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table order with multiple item.

```
Order  Item
-----------
1      bag
1      pen
1      pencil
2      bag
2      pen
```

if order does not have a item "pencil" and then sql will the order.
otherwise it will not return.

Comment: order:-1 item:-bag

Comment: It's really hard, if not impossible to tell, what exactly you are asking. Please have a look at the SO help page about how to ask and then try to restate your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you please show the expected result for the table data shown?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you want:

```
SELECT * 
from order y
WHERE not exists (select Item from order x where Item = 'pencil' and x.Order = y.order)
```